# Is it possible to render AMP components from JSON inside of amp-list?

Tags: amp-html

I am working on creating an ASP.NET MVC application to transform content from a content management system and render it as an AMP-compliant page. The CMS has a concept called lists, which groups together content items of a particular template, each which can have custom fields of different types (plain text, boolean, HTML, etc.).

The amp-list component allows you to render raw HTML by using triple curly braces rather than double, for example `{{{htmlProperty}}}`. This works in general, but I'm running into an issue with it stripping out images, even if I modify them server-side to use proper amp-img syntax.

I have the following amp-list component:

```
<amp-list layout="fixed-height" height="500" src="https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56eb207e-e2c3-11e8-a8cb-676415a24d50" single-item>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{#contentItems}}
        <section>
            <header>
                {{title}}
            </header>
            <div>
                {{{content}}}
            </div>
        </section>
        {{/contentItems}}
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

I have the following sample JSON:

```
{
  "totalRecords": 2,
  "pageSize": 0,
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "items": {
    "contentItems": [
      {
        "row": 1,
        "title": "What is your favorite sport?",
        "content": "<p><strong>Hockey</strong></p>"
      },
      {
        "row": 2,
        "title": "What is your favorite country?",
        "content": "<p>Canada</p><amp-img src=\"http://www.flagblvd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/canadian-flag-medium.png\" alt=\"\" layout=\"fill\"></amp-img>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the `title` property is plain text while `content` is HTML. When the page is loaded, the bold from the `<strong>` tag in the first content item works, but you'll notice the amp-img is omitted from the output if you inspect in your browser's developer console. Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dab0yuh5/) for a demonstration.

Is there any way to get this to work properly? I didn't see anything about this in the [official documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list). I only even found out about using the triple braces to render raw HTML by seeing it used in [an example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/) with no corresponding documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of "triple-mustache" is sanitized to only allow the following tags: `a`, `b`,`br`, `caption`, `colgroup`, `code`, `del`, `div`, `em`, `i`, `ins`, `li`, `mark`, `ol`, `p`, `q`, `s`, `small`, `span`, `strong`, `sub`, `sup`, `table`, `tbody`, `time`, `td`, `th`, `thead`, `tfoot`, `tr`, `u`, `ul`.

[**For More Information**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the correct answer; I am surprised that amp-* components are not included in the list of acceptable tags. I found a [ticket](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15343) that indicates this is by design.