# Display Raw HTML from json to AMP page

Tags: amp-html

Currently, I'm trying to implement AMP to an existing Product page and I'm a little bit stuck on displaying some data.

The field which I'm trying to display comes from json and contains Raw HTML (something like the following):

```
description: { '<h1>section title</h1><p>section description</p>' }
```

On the AMP documentation I couldn't find any informations about displaying/converting the above string into default HTML tags.

Could you tell me please if there is a way to achieve this with AMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render raw HTML by using triple curly braces rather than double, for example `{{{htmlProperty}}}` like `{{{description}}}`

`<h1>` tag is not supported

[For more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205299/5635098)

Comment: Works as it should! Thank you very much @Bachcha!